# Calling visit() in acceptance test for Ember 2.2.0 times out

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

New Ember developer coming from a Rails world. Developing my first Ember client side app to interact with a Rails app for our API endpoint.

Using Ember 2.2.0, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage 0.1.11, and PhantomJS 2.0.0, somehow, when calling `visit('/facilities')` in an acceptance test, all I get is a timeout.

My `app/mirage/config.js` file seems to be properly set up with the following:

```
export default function() {
  this.get('/facilities');
  this.get('/facilities/:facility_id');
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: It should be noted that "visit('/');" somehow works just fine.

Comment: Okay, I guess my mind was foggy. I was actually trying to mock URLs of my client side app while I had to mock URLs for my API app. Which is obvious by now, but I wasn't thinking then. So, I had to set "this.namespace = 'http://localhost:3000/v1'". Not everything is working yet, but I'm progressing.

Comment: If you run mirage in development mode (as to not hit your rails api, does the app work?)